# Highcharts pie wrong legend colors

Tags: css, charts, highcharts

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The Slice color and the Legend color of the Pie-Chart do not match when the color is set using className. Doing this for (some) other charts works.

As you can see in the following code snippet, the pie slice and the Legend color for Chrome do not match.

```js
// Build the chart
Highcharts.chart('container-donut', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            showInLegend: true,
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'browsers',
        data: [
            { 
             name: 'Chrome', 
             y: 60 ,
              className: 'MyCustomColor'
            },
            { name: 'Internet Explorer', y: 5 },
            { name: 'Firefox', y: 5 },
            { name: 'Edge', y: 5 },
            { name: 'Safari', y: 5 },
            { name: 'Other', y: 5 }
        ]
    }]
});
```

```css
.MyCustomColor {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>



<div id="container-donut" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


<div id="container-column" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Why not change `className: 'MyCustomColor'` to `color: 'green'`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/wj9gf3pL/19/ ?

Comment: True, using Color indeed works, but my goal here is to use a sass variable $MyThemeGreen as the color so that the chart color also changes when changing my theme styling. so i dont want the color hardcoded in the Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css is not accessing the legend element, which is a `<rect>` inside of the `<g class="MyCustomColor">`

Changing your css to this should solve your issue:

```
.MyCustomColor, .MyCustomColor rect {
  fill: green;
}
```